# Using JavaScript to generate fresh tables on user selection change

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working in JavaScript for just a few days and am trying to complete a small project.

I have a webpage that generates new data for a table based on user input via a Select element. In it's current state, I am able to get the information to populate into the table but am having issues when trying to clear data for a new selection.

When the selection is changed, the fillClassTable() function is called which adds the new data into newly generated rows / cells. I would like to either manage to reset the table to just the header columns prior to generating these new rows **or** be able to remove the old entries from the latter rows of the table (in this case the bottom 4 rows) after generation occurs.

So far, when I have implemented any sort of statement like classTable.remove() or classTable.removeChild() it disables all of my generation even if I pass in just one row as a parameter.

```js
// Fills class table using parameters attached to student status.
function fillClassTable(className1, className2, className3, className4) {

  // If table data has been generated, clear before regeneration.
  if (tableGenerated == true) {
    // How do I clear the table down to just my preset th's prior to
    // population of new data?
  }

  // Get table from HTML.
  let classTable = document.getElementById('classtable');

  // Create a new row in our table.
  let row1 = classTable.insertRow(1);
  // Insert cell into row for course title.
  let courseNameCell1 = row1.insertCell(0);
  courseNameCell1.innerHTML = className1;
  // Insert cell for Grade select dropdown.
  let courseGradeCell1 = row1.insertCell(1);
  courseGradeCell1.setAttribute('id', 'course1GradeValue');
  // Fill our new select element into our Grade Select cell.
  courseGradeCell1.appendChild(fillGradeSelect());

  let row2 = classTable.insertRow(2);
  let courseNameCell2 = row2.insertCell(0);
  courseNameCell2.innerHTML = className2;
  let courseGradeCell2 = row2.insertCell(1);
  courseGradeCell2.setAttribute('id', 'course2GradeValue');
  courseGradeCell2.appendChild(fillGradeSelect());

  let row3 = classTable.insertRow(3);
  let courseNameCell3 = row3.insertCell(0);
  courseNameCell3.innerHTML = className3;
  let courseGradeCell3 = row3.insertCell(1);
  courseGradeCell3.setAttribute('id', 'course3GradeValue');
  courseGradeCell3.appendChild(fillGradeSelect());

  let row4 = classTable.insertRow(4);
  let courseNameCell4 = row4.insertCell(0);
  courseNameCell4.innerHTML = className4;
  let courseGradeCell4 = row4.insertCell(1);
  courseGradeCell4.setAttribute('id', 'course4GradeValue');
  courseGradeCell4.appendChild(fillGradeSelect());

  // Notify us that table has been generated.
  tableGenerated = true;
}
```

```html
<div class="eligibilityformsection">
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <ul class="elibilityform_elementlist">
      <li>
        <label class="form_label" for="student_status">Student Status:</label>
        <!-- Send selected value to .js file to process unique table per selection. -->
        <select class="student_status_dropdown" id="student_status" name="student_status" onchange="DisplayClasses(value)">
          <option value="freshman">Freshman</option>
          <option value="sophomore">Sophomore</option>
          <option value="junior">Junior</option>
          <option value="senior">Senior</option>
        </select>
      </li>
      <br>
      <li>
        <table class="form_classtable" id="classtable">
          <tr class="header_row">
            <th>Course Title</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to easily reset a table use this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].innerHTML = "";
```

This will set the value inside the `<tbody>` tag to nothing, therefor resetting the table